# Fix the columns height in css

Tags: css, height

I have the following CSS source:

```
/**Track Properties***/
#area {
    font-size: 14px;
}
conteiner {
    height:100%;

}
.track {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
}

.trackdetails {
    position: relative;
    top: -450px;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-right: 2px solid #9e9e9e;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    left:100px;

}


    .trackdetails #title {
        color: #3852A4;
        font-size: large;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .trackdetails #content {
        z-index: 1111;
    }

#trackdescription {
    width: 550px;
    text-align: justify;
    min-height: 400px;
}



/**END**/
```

And this HTML/ASPX source:

```
 <div class="track">

        <h1><%=TrackName %></h1>

        <div class="details">
            <span id="author">מאת: <%=FullName %>,</span>
            <span id="date">פורסם בתאריך: <%=PostDate%></span>

            <div>
                <span id="area"><b>איזור: </b><%=TrackLocation %></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="trackdescription">
            <%=TrackDescription %><p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="trackdetails">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="title">פרטים נוספים</div>
                <p>
                    <b>רמת קושי:</b>  <%=DifficultLevel %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>מעגלי?</b> <%=IsCircular %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>מתאים למתחילים?</b>  <%=ForBeginners %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>משך המסלול:</b> <%=TrackDuration %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>אורך המסלול:</b> <%=TrackLength %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>טיפוס מצטבר:</b> <%=OverallHeight %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>עונה מומלצת:</b> <%=Season %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>נקודת התחלה:</b> <%=StartPoint %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>מקום חניה:</b> <%=ParkingPlace %>
                     <b>מקום חניה:</b> <%=ParkingPlace %> <b>מקום חניה:</b> <%=ParkingPlace %> <b>מקום חניה:</b> <%=ParkingPlace %> <b>מקום חניה:</b> <%=ParkingPlace %> <b>מקום חניה:</b> <%=ParkingPlace %> <b>מקום חניה:</b> <%=ParkingPlace %> <b>מקום חניה:</b> <%=ParkingPlace %>
                </p>
            </div>    </div>

        </div>
        תמונות <%=images %><p></p>
        מפה : <%=result2%><p></p>
```

The problm is that I got this result, and some content is 'on' other content (There is a PrintScreen)
My question is why and how can I fix this?
Wish for help, thanks.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Can you give us a link to your website?

Comment: Hi @kat_indo, i'm sorry but I works on it, right now it is in Localhost...

Comment: You should take the images in div and then move them to specified position.

Comment: The problem is that the height of the columns changes for every article (This is dynamic page)...

Comment: I tried to change the position from relative to absulut, tried to change the display to dislay:table but nothing realyy work...

Comment: Where do you want these images??

Comment: Under the text, not on the text...

Comment: within left sidebar or under content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css

```
#image{width:600px;
height:50px;
float:right;}

#result{width:600px;
height:50px;
float:right;}
```

and use div like this in html

```
<div id="image">?????? <%=images %><p></p></div>
<div id="result">??? : <%=result2%><p></p></div>
```

Comment: This look the same as befor, after the update.. :(, I don't think so

Comment: problem here is that you didn't use any layout thats why the data is tough to manage.

Comment: I think it would be better for you to use any layout approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css --

```
#image{position:relative;
top:-450px;
width:1010px;
height:100px;
float:left;}

#result{position:relative;
top:-450px;
width:1010px;
height:100px;
float:left;}
```

Comment: It's ok, your advice at the first answer fix the problem, thanks again!